# getExternalFilesDir alternative in android 2.1

Tags: java, android, android-2.1-eclair

I built an android app on ***android 2.2***, for saving files into the SD card I use the following:

```
 context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

returning a string like:

```
 /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.hello.example1/files
```

Now I need to make my app compatible with ***android 2.1***, what method do I need to use to get the external files directory?

---

```
public static String sTellMeWhereToSaveMyData(Context context) 
{
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        File externalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File appFiles = new File(externalPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + packageName+ "/");

        if (appFiles.exists() && appFiles.isDirectory()) 
        {
            return appFiles.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        else 
        {
            if(appFiles.exists())
            {
                Log.v("File Manager","not exists");
            }
            if (!appFiles.mkdir())
            {
                Log.v("File Manager","Could not create");
            }   
        }
        return appFiles.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should compose the path yourself:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
File externalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File appFiles = new File(externalPath.getAbsolutePath() +
                         "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files");
```

Comment: you have 2 issues here: 1. it's **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** 2. close the bracket after **+"/files")**

Comment: Fixed that. I didn't check this code with compiler. But anyway, this should've shown what I meant.

Comment: @inazaruk: perfect I am testing that right away, I got it before you edited it, my comment was just for the sake of the other people who might face the same issue.

Comment: Thanks :) Also note that on Android 2.1 (and lower) this folder might not get deleted if application is uninstalled.

Comment: @inazaruk: there is a weird behavior I am facing, when i ask about if the File `appFiles` does exist it returns no, do you have any idea?

Comment: Do I need to create it my self?

Comment: Yes, you need. Use `appFiles.mkdirs()`.

Comment: unfortunately it always returns false flag after executing it.

Comment: If `mkdirs()` function returns false, then the directory already exists. Check it with `appFiled.exists()` or use file browser to verify it was created.

Comment: @inazaruk: Kindly check my updated answer, all I want to do is to get the path where the download file is going to be stored, I know I have been a pain to you, I Am really appreciated.

Comment: Hi inazaruk.. This post looks similar to my problem. In android 2.1 updated i can't store image in specified path.. I am really weird.. I hope you will solve my problem and help me to get to next stage...  If you can please see my [post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079515/camera-image-stored-in-dcim-but-not-in-the-specified-folder).thanks in advance..